# Noun Project API in Java - no access token

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I'm really struggling with this..

I'm trying to access the Noun Project API via Java (there are examples in Node.js (doesn't work for me because my app is SSL), Ruby etc - nothing in Java)

It's different from the standard libraries I can find, as it doesn't require a token

> The API is secured with OAuth 1.0a. You must use your client key and
>   secret to sign requests when accessing the API. There are many
>   established libraries that will take care of authenticating calls for
>   you. There is no need to provide an access token as our API endpoints
>   do not yet support granting access to a users private data.

I've been trying with scribeJava to get the request, it returns the data I need in the token request as shown in this question [JavaScribe without needing an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534571/javascribe-without-needing-an-access-token)

Please can someone explain how I just make a signed request with no token? I've spent 2 days on this now and I'm totally confused

Comment: You want to sign a request without having a token? This sounds impossible to me. *(I know nothing about the apis you want to use so they might have build something for this)*

Comment: http://api.thenounproject.com/getting_started.html#authentication - There is not need to provide an access token. Not sure if that means I can't get a token?